# How to use additional non-visual data for image classification?

Tags: neural-networks, classification, conv-neural-network, computer-vision

I've got a Resnet network that classifies images into n classes and is working fine. I want to boost its performance buy using additional information I have regarding the images. This info comes in two forms:

1. The subclass of the image. Denote m sub classes.
2. The method used to take the image (one of two options, may inflect lightly the colors of the image)

For some of the images I have only the first kinda of additional data, for some the second, for some both and for some none.

How may I utilize each kind of such data?
I thought of the following:

1. For the first kind of data, enlarge the last FC layer size from n to m. the total loss would be comprised as a sum of
   a) a loss computed for the subclass after applying softmax to the m neurons and
   b) a loss computed by summing each group of subclasses to their respective class, then applying the original softmax loss i am using now.
2. for the second kinda of data, i thought of connecting a single bit that denotes the method in which the image was taken to the final FC layer. It will actually be a trit and not a bit, because for some images the data is missing.

Will those methods work? Are there better ways of utilizing this additional data? What do I do in case the data is missing for some samples?

Comment: Looks like a good scenario for *multi-task learning*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those methods are valid. You can even inject those auxiliary inputs earlier into the network by "tiling them" -- that is, if you have some K-dimensional vector of auxiliary inputs, copy it on the height and width axes until you have a KxHxW tensor, and concatenate it to some intermediate feature map of your CNN.

You could use one-hot coding for categorical inputs with possibly missing data (simply set everything to 0 if unknown).